# How to create .apk from HelloWorld sample of Cocos2dx?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am using Windows 7 x64, cygwin, Eclipse Juno cpp, jre6, android ndk r8b, latest cocos2dx for windows. I have tried this tutorial link.
http://www.cnblogs.com/ybgame/archive/2012/06/07/2540693.html

I have overcome the error. But unfortunately, the Eclipse builder don't generate the .apk file. The console's output is here:
[image]

Notice that, there is no "make" command called. This is different from the tutorial link above, where the last part of tutorial, the console's output is showing the make command called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on your Eclipse Project -> Android Tools-> Export signed (or unsigned) Application Package

Comment: That's not the case. I am using cocos2dx, with the base code is C/C++.

Comment: I know is c++. what cocos2d-x did is, it compile itself together with the game logic code to a java library, then you do whatever you did as if you are developing an Java project in android sdk

Answer (score 0):

compile the project in msys or cygwin and then import/ create project from source and give a name. click on the run button.you will notice the project run on emulator all is set . good luck.